# 2 questions about optimizing stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to speed up my stored procedures, after some research online, I have 2 questions arisen:

Question #1: should I transfer all the parameters to local variable?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(@test nvarchar(MAX))
AS
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     SELECT * FROM my_table
     WHERE my_column = @test;
```

VS

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(@test nvarchar(MAX))
AS
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     Declare @locTest nvarchar(MAX);
     Set @locTest = @test;

     SELECT * FROM my_table
     WHERE my_column = @locTest;
```

In general cases, which one above is going to run faster?

Question #2: inside a stored procedure, should I call a stored procedure to execute a simple one line query or just write the query directly?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(@test nvarchar(MAX), @username nvarchar(MAX))
AS
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     INSERT INTO AuditTable
     Values(NEWID(), @test, @username, getdate());
```

VS

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(@test nvarchar(MAX),@username nvarchar(MAX))
AS
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     EXEC InsertAudit @value = @test, @username = @username;

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertAudit(@value nvarchar(MAX), @username nvarchar(MAX))
AS
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     INSERT INTO AuditTable
     Values(NEWID(), @value, @username, getdate());
```

This one might be obvious but I still want to make sure which one above is going to run faster in general cases.

And this title is pretty uninformative, but couldn't come up any better one.

Thank you.

Comment: You should not ever send to an audit table from a stored proc. Auditing needs to happen no matter how the data inteh table was changed and thus it MUST be ina trigger. It also  musSt be written to handle multiple record inserts/updates so a values clause is not appropriate.

Comment: Are the columns in the database that you are inserting to nvarhar(max)? Your parameters should match the datatype of the column they will insert to. If all your columns are nvarchar (max) then you need to redesign ASAP as those cannot be indexed and you will always have bad performance without indexing.

Comment: @HLGEM, originally I handled audit table in triggers, but audit table requires username, since my application is written in asp.net,javascript and c#, I couldn't find a efficient way to get username from javascript to triggers. Any suggestion?

Comment: I agree that in general you should not do either. However, when it comes to performance the best thing you can do is to evaluate the performance of the actual code. Above all, do not make non standard design decisions based on performance issues that have not materialized.

Comment: @SSilicon, I would add a lastupdatedby column and populate that in my sps. then you can easily pull it for the audit trigger  and for a quick look you can see who did it right then. There are also variables that can pull the user, but I am assuming you mean the  application uses a general user and you want the specific person.

Comment: @HLGEM, yes, I have a login page in my application and the user who logged in can modify database through the application, I can set a trigger in database and insert audit whenever the database is changed. But I have a modifiedBy column in audit table which requires user name, and there's no way I can populate that column within the trigger.

Comment: That's why I suggested sending in the username to a field in the table everytime the table is modifed by your procs.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, yes using local variables can speed up performance due to parameter sniffing. As with all performance tuning though, it is subject to the design of your particular database and the amount and type of data you have as well as other factors such as indexing, etc. So just making this change may or may not speed things up considerably. If something like lack of indexes is causing your problem, then this change won't fix that.

If the work being done in the second stored proc is something you will need to add to many procs, then yes, it should be a separate proc, so that you only need to fix in one place if there is a bug. However, there is no circumstance where it is appropriate to insert to audit table from a proc. These must **under all conditions** be done only from a trigger or you will miss many of the record changes that need to be audited. I can't say this too strongly, auditing is never appropriate from the application or from a stored proc. NEVER!!!!! Often the very things you need to find from auditing are from unauthorized changes that happened outside your application.

Answer (score 1):

1:   In general cases, they will run about the same.   The argument for using local variables to replace your parameters is that it eliminates bad cached execution plans caused by parameter sniffing.   With your example, I would choose "B".

2:  I would not create a nested stored proc to handle only a single query.   Performance differences will be negligible, and you'll create a maintenance hassle.   So in your example, I would choose "A".